# Heroku git command get rejected?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

Hello guys my " git push heroku master " command get rejected...why? im using w10 power shell..Before rejection it says "no default language could be detected for this app".Please help me guys..[heroku error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StafE.png)

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. What are you trying to achieve? What do you/don't you understand about the error? What research have you done to try and solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku is having trouble recognising what app you are trying to run make sure you have a `requirements.txt` file in the root that installs all your dependencies as well as `gunicorn` you should also create a `Procfile`
` in the root of your code with the following ( replace gettingstarted with the name of your Django project.)

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi
```

more info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn)